# Smarty highlight in eclipse luna pdt

Tags: eclipse, smarty, eclipse-pdt

As shown in last comments here https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/wiki/InstallSmartyPDT
smartypdt plugin seems not working in eclipse luna.
I used eclipse indigo before. I am wondering if there is a way to export something in indigo version where smartypdt works and import it to luna.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartyPDT is not compatible with PDT >= 3.2 due changed feature name. Looks like this project is no longer maintained.

https://code.google.com/p/smartypdt/issues/detail?id=73

**Edit:**

PDT Extension Group provide now own SmartyPDT compilation, see [p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org](http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/)

This version is compatible with latest PDT (3.2 and 3.3)

Comment: Sorry but I have not understand the way to use it. So you have any guide on this? I can not see a jar file to install

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/#download see "update existing eclipse", your p2 update site is a p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm that by adding this url http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org in install new software and selecting Smarty, it works also in Luna pdt